# How can i get x_train from ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification, avassetimagegenerator

im working on image classification CNN and i'm wondering how can i get x_train and y_train form using ImageGenerator. the reason of this is i want to fit my model as fit note fit.generator

```
trainDataGen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale= 1./255,
                                 rotation_range =30,
                                 width_shift_range=0.1,
                                 height_shift_range=0.1,
                                 shear_range=0.2,
                                 zoom_range=0.2,
                                 horizontal_flip=False,
                                 vertical_flip=False,
                                 fill_mode='nearest',                                
                                 )

trainGenSet = trainDataGen.flow_from_directory(
    path +'Train',
    target_size=(28,28),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical',
    color_mode='grayscale',
)


x_train, y_train = trainGenSet.next()
```

the print(x_train) is (32,28,28,1)
because of the batch size 32.
i have total 5000 of train data Set
and i want to get (5000,28,28,1) for print(x_train)

Comment: Hello James Did you find a solution to this